# Ember Root URL Based Navigation

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, frontend, ember-cli

I have mainly been working as a back-end developer. Recently however, I have begun dabbling with the Ember front-end framework. I have a requirement such that two Ember apps should be served from same domain.

Specifying a root URL: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/#toc_specifying-a-root-url

Let's say I am serving the website from http://example.com

App1 is served from http://example.com/foo/

App2 is served from http://example.com/bar/

Here is the sample configuration I used for `environment.js`:

**App 1:**

```
let ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'my-app',
    environment,
    rootURL: '/foo/',
    locationType: 'hash'
}
```

**App 2:**

```
let ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'my-app',
    environment,
    rootURL: '/bar/',
    locationType: 'hash'
}
```

After making these changes I expect them to work fine. However, when I visit 'App2' served from http://example.com/bar/client#/route/route-page, it is showing `rootURL` as `/foo/` in Ember Inspector.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it worked. I guess Ember uses the module-prefix to distinguish both the apps. module-prefix is the application name for each Ember app. Since I have given the same module-prefix for each app, it resulted in the same app being invoked for each root URL causing the issue. This is the possible explanation I have.